# DQL zipcode distance from association

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, dql

going crazy over this.. as usual its probably something stupidly simple im just not seeing. 3 objects:`Person` `Address` `Zip`

`Person` has a OneToMany association to `Address`

`Address` has a ManyToOne association to `Zip`

`Zip` has a `lat` and `lon` field

Now i want to select all persons within x kilometer from a lat/lon.
So i got the following DQL:

`SELECT c, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(52.377778951201) ) * cos( radians( z.lat ) ) * cos( radians( z.lon ) - radians(4.9055895401203) ) + sin( radians(52.377778951201) ) * sin( radians( z.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Person c LEFT JOIN c.addresses addr LEFT JOIN addr.zip z HAVING distance < ?4`

this gives 0 results so i try it without the `HAVING distance < ?4` but then it still has 0 results.

What am i not seeing??

UPDATE (answer, kind off..):

After executing the generated SQL (thanks to @ChrisC) i found that i get the results as expected.
So had to do some digging in the code handling the `QueryBuilder`.
i use following code to create a `Paginator`:

```
$adapter = new DoctrineAdapter(new ORMPaginator($qb));
$paginator = new Paginator($adapter, true);
$paginator->setDefaultItemCountPerPage(10);
```

where `$qb` is a Doctrine `QueryBuilder`

In my view i do a foreach: `foreach ($paginator as $entity)`
This works as expected for almost every query i create with the `QueryBuilder`
But when i try the select from above `$entity` is no longer a `Person` object but a array containing the `Person` object as its first element. As a temporary solution i now do the following in my view: `if (!is_object($entity)) $entity = $entity[0];`

Not a real solution but will do for now.

Comment: I don't know if you can change, but postgresql has great features using postgis to do location queries.  You can easily find all people within a geometry or can find people within a radius of a point.

Comment: I could change but thats not the point, the distance calculation is correct. The problem is with the associations and joins i believe.

Comment: If you drop the Having clause, you should return all rows in Person, but this sounds like a join is not working correctly.  Can you post your entity associations for the 3 entities.

Comment: Can you share your entity mappings please?

Comment: not sure if that will change something but why don't you put the on clause on the left joins? also, have you tried to run the query only on the mysql console, or phpmyadmin? so at least we may understand if the problem is the query, the entities or the relationship.

Comment: sorry for the delay, added the relevant mappings. @BrunoQuintanaFleitas it is DQL not SQL so i can't execute it in mysql console and there is no ON clause.

Comment: You should be able to get the SQL, which will make debugging this easier.  You can do this by using the `getSql()` method of the `Query` class, or Zend Framework likely has some kind of query logging functionality.

Comment: @ChrisC Thanks for the tip! Got me to find the problem! Updated the question.

Comment: Is the reason you get an array because you have selected an extra column (distance)? If you don't need the distance, you could move the whole calculation to the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 0):

It is like Arth already suggests in his comment. You get an array because the `SELECT` clause is not interpreted as a `fetch join` but as if you query for both `c` (Person) and `distance`. Because of this you get the result in an Array with `c` as the first member and `distance` as the second. You need to move the `...... AS distance` out of the `SELECT` clause. I think it should work then.